# ":" from Matlab to Python

Tags: python, matlab

I am new to **Python** and **Matlab** but, i was wondering what ***":"*** does in matlab on this case
`t1=(n-1)*pi:2*pi/2000:n*pi-2*pi/2000;` and how it can be converted to Python.

Comment: MATLAB has *excellent* [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colon.html).

Answer (score 2):

The ":" notation in Matlab refers to 3 different uses (as far as I remember), in your case we're talking about vector creation:

```matlab
vec = start:step:stop
```

or

```matlab
vec = start:stop %if step is 1 you don't need to specify it
```

The other posible use is to tell Matlab that you need all the elements in one dimension of your matrix (let's say all the columns or al the rows).

```matlab
A = [1,2,3; 4,5,6] ;
A(:,1) %means all rows for the first column ->[1;4]
A(1,:) %means all columns for the first row -> [1,2,3]
```

And last you can use the ":" to vectorize any N-Dimensional matrix:

```matlab
A(:) %means all elements in A as a vector (stack of colums)-> [1,4,2,5,3,6]
```

With all that said, remember that when you use a for you're actually iterating over a vector.

```matlab
for i=1:4 %create the vector 1,2,3,4 and then use i as this values
    doSomething
end
```

Last, talking about Python, if you're working with vectors and matrices in a mathematical way I would recomend you to use some library (NumPy is usually the best option). I most cases you can use the `numpy.arange` to create a vector from `start` to `stop` with a `step`:

```py
import numpy as np
vec = np.arange(start,stop,step) %equivalent to start:step:stop in Matlab
```

and if you want the exact vector in your example your `start` would be `(n-1)*pi` , your `step` `2*pi/2000`, and your stop `n*pi` then you substrtact `2*pi/2000`. In NumPy you can call pi as `np.pi`:

```py
t1 = np.arange( (n-1)*np.pi, n*np.pi,2*np.pi/2000 ) -2*np.pi/2000
```

As a pythonist now I have to make this *statement*: there are other ways to create arrays in Python, but I’m trying to use the Matlab analogous not the "Python way". That is becuase I think it's a way to start understanging the language at first.